# How to stop Recycle Bin from deleting files by default in My Files?

Tags: applications, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've installed Omega Droid, which comes with [Recycle Bin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.recyclebin&hl=en) as a system app - I cannot uninstall it. Normally it doesn't bother me, but when I browse my files in the My Files system app and click a file that has no application registered it gets "handled" by the Recycle Bin app, which kindly deletes it for me without any confirmation! Of course, I can go into the app and restore the file, but this is really annoying. How do stop Recycle Bin from handling any type of file? I don't want to ever use it at all. I would uninstall it if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to remove system apps. Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en) and it will allow you to remove any app you wish, system or not.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea that's possible - thanks! Removed the Recycle Bin app and that solved the problem.